# How to use vim.loop interactively in Neovim?

Tags: neovim, vimscript-lua

I want to read texts with Neovim scrolling them down automatically. The following code
provides such functionality:

```lua
local M = {}

function M.down()
    local timer = vim.loop.new_timer()
    local stop = false
    local sleep = 5000
    timer:start(1000, sleep, vim.schedule_wrap(function()
      local scroll_down = vim.api.nvim_replace_termcodes('normal <C-E>', true, true, true)
      vim.cmd(scroll_down)

      if stop then
        timer:close()
      end
    end))
end

return M
```

How can I interact with `vim.loop` by changing `stop` and `sleep` variables, so the scrolling can be made faster/slower, or stopped?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't modify the attributes of a timer while it's running. You'd have to kill the existing timer and start a new one with a new time. As for `stop` you could use a global variable instead of a local and change that from anywhere, I guess.

Comment: Yes @B Layer, I thought about global variables, but would love to avoid them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incorporating @B Layer's feedback I came up with the following code, that is able to stop scrolling, make it slower/faster without creating global variables.

```lua
local M = {sleep = 1000, timer = nil}

function M.down()
    print(M.sleep)
    M.timer = vim.loop.new_timer()
    M.timer:start(1000, M.sleep, vim.schedule_wrap(function()
      local down = vim.api.nvim_replace_termcodes('normal <C-E>', true, true, true)
      vim.cmd(down)
    end))
end

function M.down_stop()
  if M.timer ~= nil then
    M.timer:close()
    M.timer = nil
  end
end

function M.down_slower()
  M.down_change(2)
end

function M.down_faster()
  M.down_change(0.5)
end

function M.down_change(n)
  M.down_stop()
  M.sleep = M.sleep*n
  M.down()
end

return M
```

Comment: Cool. Glad my comment was of some value. :)